# Put own question on hold

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think there are times when it would be helpful to be able to put one's own question (or answer) on hold.

There are containers for draft questions within Meta, which gives users an environment in which to edit and draft questions and answers before posting.  But sometimes having already posted something, users quickly point out shortcomings that would be better addressed before other users invest further time.

Putting one's own question on hold would be a way to acknowledge that matters need to be addressed and to have a moratorium on further input until they are.

Comment: Hmmm. If you were able to put on hold in order to edit it, your first edit would immediately put it in the reopen queue, which would be a waste of users time reviewing, if you are not yet done reviewing.  And if reopened via the reopen queue, you'd need to put on hold, if you could, to continue editing, according to your scheme.  Seems to me a an ill-thought-out-question for meta.

Comment: @amWhy I have a solution now. But I guess if we could put our own questions on hold pending improvement we'd generally want to be the only one who can unhold them and no need for the reopen queue to get involved.

Comment: I think a comment that you are about to edit your question would usually suffice. If for some reason you don't think this is acceptable, you could capture the content of your question (like from the edit window), delete it, paste your copied content into a sandbox (or on a new-question page --- but don't ask a new question), edit it, copy your edited content, undelete your question, and finally replace it with your edited content. But this seems pretty tedious. I think I would just edit it, and maybe add a comment if I thought it would be necessary.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks. I'm going with the tedious option. I'm often pretty slow at editing the question, by which time downvotes hit -10 and the question gets closed and deleted!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I need to do this, I **delete** my own question.  I can still work on it while it is deleted.  When (if ever) I am ready, I **undelete** it.

Note.  It seems I cannot edit my own question after deleting it.  I tried it, but when I deletete it, then click "edit" I get this...

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. The reason I've not been doing this is because I can't edit while deleted. But I guess I can use one of the sandbox questions to do that temporarily until I'm ready to undelete.

Comment: You are right.  You can delete your own answer and then edit it.

Comment: I found this thread on Meta.SE from 2013, [Edit a self-deleted Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213632/edit-a-self-deleted-question), where the Comments come around to a notion that blocking edits is intended to provide Community review by bumping a self-edited post.  The Accepted Answer by Shadow Wizard also has some thoughts on procedure that I found helpful.